# Kotlin - Return callback event

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a quick question about Kotlin,

For example I have a class A which have this field:

```
private val observer: Observer<O> = object : Observer<O> {
    override fun onChanged(output: O) {

    }
}
```

Is there any Kotlin way of returning/passing/extending the onChange event (not the value) thru a method?

I don't want to expose the output thru a listener/callback(Java way).
What I'm looking for is to somehow return the onChanged method call, without using a "middle" object/callback

Thanks

Comment: Can we return a future or deferred from the method?

Comment: Since I'm new on Kotlin I will say.. yes
In the meantime I will take a look at these

Comment: What are you doing with the returned "method call"? Not exactly clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

when we say `return` a value, it returns a value back to the callee, in this case, whoever called the `onChanged` method. This happens in case of synchronous calls.

In this case, `onChanged` call will be invoked in an asynchronous manner which makes it impossible to simply return a value back to the callee without a callback.

Comment: ...except with coroutines and suspend funs

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand your question, you can use observer.onChanged as Kotlin Function:
`val observerOnChangedFunction = observer.run { ::onChanged }`
Than you can invoke this function:
`observerOnChangedFunction(instanceOfO)`

Answer (score 0):

Usecase: `onChanged` as `var` field

```
class Foo<O> {

   var onChanged: (O) -> Unit = { /* default */}

   private val observer: Observer<O> = object : Observer<O> {
      override fun onChanged(output: O) = onChanged(output)
   }
}

fun main() {
   val foo = Foo<Int>()
   foo.onChanged = { it.toString() }
}
```

-

Usecase: parameter in constructor as observer

```
class Foo<O> (
   observer: Observer<O>
) {
   private val observer: Observer<O> = observer
}
```

-

Usecase: parameter in constructor as `onChanged` lambda

```
class Foo<O> (
   onChanged: (O) -> Unit
) {
   private val observer: Observer<O> = object : Observer<O> {
      override fun onChanged(output: O) = onChanged(output)
   }
}
```